# Measure Theory - a function is measurable in the product measure

Tags: measure-theory

This is connected to the question [Showing a function is measurable in a product measure space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249571/showing-a-function-is-measurable-in-a-product-measure-space)

The question was that given two measurable spaces $(A,M)$ and $(B,N)$ with the real-valued functions f and g being $M$ and $N$ measurable respectively, show that $f(x)g(y)$ is $M \times N$-measurable.

The accepted answer suggested to define $\tilde{f}(x,y)=f(x)$ and $\tilde{g}(x,y)=g(y)$, then $\tilde{f}^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)=f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)\times B$ and $\tilde{g}^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)=A \times g^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)$ are $M \times N$-measurable.

My question is why (in more detail) $\tilde{f}^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)=f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)\times B$ and $\tilde{g}^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)=A \times g^{-1}(\alpha, \infty)$ are $M \times N$-measurable?

Comment: By definition of the product $\sigma$-algebra, the projections onto $M$ and $N$ are both measurable. Since the composition of measurable functions and the product of measurable functions is measurable, this proves that $f(x)g(y)$ is measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we take the space $M \times N$ to be endowed with the product sigma-algebra of measurable spaces. Such sigma-algebra is defined to be the finest such that the projection mappings will be measurable. Now suppose that the set $\tilde{f}^{-1} (\alpha, \infty) = f^{-1} (\alpha, \infty) \times B$ is not measurable.
Now take the projection mapping $\pi_1 : M \times N \mapsto M$ such that $\pi_1 (A \times B) = A$. Thus, we obtain:  $\pi_1 (f^{-1} (\alpha, \infty) \times B) = f^{-1} (\alpha, \infty)$, which is thus non-measurable. Contradiction as $f$ is measurable by assumption.